# Gradients on Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

How can I set gradient effects on pie charts?

```
[{
label: i, 
data: 1000,
color: [ "rgb(190,110,110)", "rgb(140, 70, 70)", "rgb(110, 50, 50)", "rgb(60, 10, 10)" ]
},
//nextserie
]
```

doesn't work.

Also how can I set gradient effects as default colors for my charts? In the way you can index it by number like:

```
[{
label: i, 
data: 1000,
color: 1,
},
//nextserie
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have now added support for rendering pie chart with gradients, either radial or linear.  My commit is referenced in [pull request #853](https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/853).

An example "default" pie chart with a radial gradient:

```
$.plot($("#default_gradient"), data, {
    series: {
      pie: {
        show: true,
        gradient: {
          radial: true,
          colors: [
            {opacity: 0.5},
            {opacity: 1.0}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
});
```

[image: A simple pie chart with a radial gradient]

An example donut chart with a radial gradient:

```
$.plot($("#donut_gradient"), data,
  {
    series: {
      pie: {
        innerRadius: 0.5,
        show: true,
        gradient: {
          radial: true,
          colors: [
            {opacity: 1.0},
            {opacity: 1.0},
            {opacity: 1.0},
            {opacity: 0.5},
            {opacity: 1.0}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
});
```

[image: A donut chart with a radial gradient]

An example of a tilted pie chart with a radial gradient:

```
  $.plot($("#graph9_gradient"), data,
  {
    series: {
      pie: {
        show: true,
        radius: 1,
        tilt: 0.5,
        gradient: {
          radial: true,
          colors: [
            {opacity: 0.5},
            {opacity: 1.0}
          ]
        },
        label: {
          show: true,
          radius: 1,
          formatter: function(label, series){
            return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:white;">'+label+'<br/>'+Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
          },
          background: { opacity: 0.8 }
        },
        combine: {
          color: '#999',
          threshold: 0.1
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    }
  });
```

[image: A tilted pie chart with a radial gradient]

The changes were based on a combination of the above suggestions proposed by @Hoffman and [a patch](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/attachmentText?id=276&aid=-7836171024142142196&name=jquery.flot.pie.js.diff&token=tdgA5GznNuCNK1GGcX4i_iBRGz4%3A1351838091521) suggested in [Flot issue #355](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/355) by [Luc Boudreau](http://code.google.com/u/lucboudreau/).

Comment: Hey man very cool. I accepted your answer, it's probably a lot less hacky than mine. Tell me, does it work wit tilt effect?

Comment: @Hoffmann, thanks for accepting my answer.  I have updated my answer to include an example with a tilted pie chart, and it seems to work, at least according to my expectations.  It also worked with a linear gradient, but it looked bad, so I didn't include an example of it.

Comment: Hey @mtr, there is a bug when using linear gradients. They only cover half the pie chart. To fix it on the drawSlice function change to this: gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, -bottom/2, 0, bottom/2) note that this doesn't use the top property anymore so I'm unsure if it will fix 100% on charts that are not on the center of the plot (maybe add half the top to both non-zero parameters?). Anyway the gradient is also set to start from the bottom of the plot area not the start of the pie making it bad on charts in which the pie does not cover the plot area fully. Radial gradients are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I did it myself. Took me a while to understand how flot works internally, but eventually I found the part where I needed to change. On jquery.flot.pie.js change the drawSlice function (line 406 on Flot 0.7) to:

```
            function drawSlice(angle, color, fill)
            {   
                if (angle<=0)
                    return;


                if (fill) {
                    if (typeof color === "object") {
                        var grad= ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, radius);
                        var i;
                        var numColors= color.colors.length;
                        for (i=0; i< numColors ; i++) {
                            grad.addColorStop(i/(numColors-1), color.colors[i]);
                        }
                        ctx.fillStyle = grad; 
                    } else {
                        ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    }
                    ctx.fillStyle = color;
                } else {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
                    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
                }
```

don't remove the rest of the code after the if.

And like magic now you can define your series with radial gradient colors:

```
[{
            label: i, 
            data: Math.random() *1000,
            color: { colors: [ "rgb(190,110,110)", "rgb(140, 70, 70)", "rgb(110, 50, 50)", "rgb(60, 10, 10)" ] }
}]
```

I will try to make a cool graph then I will screenshot it and post here.

EDIT: Here you go:

[image]

```
var d1= [];
    d1.push({
        label: "Crítico", 
        data: Math.random() *1000,
        color: { colors: [ "rgb(190,110,110)", "rgb(140, 70, 70)", "rgb(110, 50, 50)", "rgb(60, 10, 10)" ] }
    });
    d1.push({
        label: "Médio", 
        data: Math.random() *1000,
        color: { colors: [ "rgb(110,110,190)", "rgb(70, 70, 140)", "rgb(50, 50, 110)", "rgb(10, 10, 60)" ] }
    })
this.plot= $.plot($div, d1);
```

It's a lot better than using solid colors, but it can get a lot better, I'm just bad at picking colors. Now I found a small problem, legends don't work with my changes, no color will be displayed on them. I'm not willing to fix that since that functionality is present on the core Flot file (which is a lot bigger and complex than the pie plugin) and I don't have much free time to mess with that.

Answer (score 0):

The library doesn't support that, currently.  If you're comfortable merging patches, there was one submitted along with [issue 355](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/355) (follow the link to the original Google Code issue to get the attachment) that adds gradients to pies.  I haven't tried it myself yet, though.

Comment: you know if this patch adds radial gradients that start at the center of the pie? Or is it just an opacity setting over the whole pie from bottom to top?

Comment: It seems that patch uses linear gradient, which is very odd for pie charts. I guess I will have to write my own then.

Comment: If you ever need the functionality @DNS check my answer