# Flot Line chart gradient fill

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

My question may or may not the duplicate of this
[Gradients on Flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844159/gradients-on-flot)

According to the above link's answer, I've tried to apply the gradient fill on a line chart. It didn't work as expected. This is the code I tried;

```
$(function () {
    var d1 = [[1,14], [2,15], [3,18], [4,16], [5,19], [6,17], [7,15], [8,16], 
        [9,20], [10,16], [11,18]];
    $.plot("#line-chart", [{
        data: d1,
        label: "Data",
        }],
        {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    fill: 0.25,
                },
                gradient: {
                    radial: true,
                    colors: [
                        {opacity: 0.5},
                        {opacity: 1.0}
                    ]
                },
                shadowSize: 0,
                points: {
                    show: true,
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 10,
                max: 22,
                tickColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.15)',
                tickDecimals: 0,
                font :{
                    lineHeight: 13,
                    style: "normal",
                    color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
                },
                shadowSize: 0,
            },
            xaxis: {
                tickColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                tickDecimals: 0,
                font : {
                    lineHeight: 13,
                    style: "normal",
                    color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)", 
                }
            },
            grid: { 
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)',
                labelMargin:10,
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                mouseActiveRadius:6,
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Help me add the gradient fill on line chart.

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried it?

Comment: @tilda: I've updated the code, pls check

Answer (score 2):

The gradient option is a special thing used by the pie plugin.  Regular series treat gradients as more like a kind of color that you can use as a series fillColor.

Take a look at the example under the [Specifying Gradients](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#specifying-gradients) section of the docs for an example.

Answer (score 2):

i use;

> grid: {
>             backgroundColor: { colors: ["#4ca8fa", "#2887da"] },

in the javascript portion to display a gradient background if that helps.